# Creating a model for use in a pipeline from a hyperparameter tuning job

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to implement the best estimator from a hyperparameter tuning job into a pipeline object to deploy an endpoint.

I've read the docs in a best effort to include the results from the tuning job in the pipeline, but I'm having trouble creating the Model() class object.

```
# This is the hyperparameter tuning job
tuner.fit({'train': s3_train, 'validation': s3_val}, 
include_cls_metadata=False)


#With a standard Model (Not from the tuner) the process was as follows:
scikit_learn_inferencee_model_name = sklearn_preprocessor.create_model()
xgb_model_name = Model(model_data=xgb_model.model_data, image=xgb_image)


model_name = 'xgb-inference-pipeline-' + timestamp_prefix
endpoint_name = 'xgb-inference-pipeline-ep-' + timestamp_prefix
sm_model = PipelineModel(
    name=model_name, 
    role=role, 
    models=[
        scikit_learn_inferencee_model_name, 
        xgb_model_name])

sm_model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge', 
endpoint_name=endpoint_name)
```

I would like to be able to cleanly instantiate a model object using my results from the tuning job and pass it into the PipelineModel object. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. Do you get any error? Refer this [notebook](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/e9c295c8538d29cc9fea2f73a29649126628064a/advanced_functionality/inference_pipeline_sparkml_xgboost_abalone/inference_pipeline_sparkml_xgboost_abalone.ipynb)  for instantiating the model from the tuner and use in inference pipeline.

Editing previous response based on the comment. To create model from the best training job of the hyperparameter tuning job, you can use below snippet

```py
from sagemaker.tuner import HyperparameterTuner
from sagemaker.estimator import Estimator
from sagemaker.model import Model

# Attach to an existing hyperparameter tuning job.
xgb_tuning_job_name = 'my_xgb_hpo_tuning_job_name'
xgb_tuner = HyperparameterTuner.attach(xgb_tuning_job_name)

# Get the best XGBoost training job name from the HPO job
xgb_best_training_job = xgb_tuner.best_training_job()
print(xgb_best_training_job)

# Attach estimator to the best training job name
xgb_best_estimator = Estimator.attach(xgb_best_training_job)

# Create model to be passed to the inference pipeline
xgb_model = Model(model_data=xgb_best_estimator.model_data,
                  role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
                  image=xgb_best_estimator.image_name)
```

Comment: I was able to build my endpoint using

`xgb_model = Model(model_data = tuner.estimator.model_data)....`

But this estimator and model doesn't reflect the best hyperparameters from my tuning job. I can find no documentation anywhere on deploying a tuner object in a pipeline. I've been trying for almost a week now.


In the notebook you linked, they do not use a hyperparameter tuning job, which created a tuner object which doesn't have a `.model_data` field.

Comment: I edited my response based on your feedback. I have not seen example in the example notebooks to create inference pipeline from the HPO job. It should not be too difficult. See if the above code snippet helps you to create inference pipeline from the best training job of HPO job.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked and the model was built properly. I've gotta go through the docs to understand the multiple attach calls... could you explain it quickly so I can resolve this problem on my own in the future?

Thank you very much. My account is too new to vote up your solution, but I've verified it as the answer.