# SageMaker: PipelineModel and Hyperparameter Tuning

Tags: python, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters

We want to tune a SageMaker [PipelineModel](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/pipeline.html) with a [HyperparameterTuner](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/tuner.html?highlight=HyperparameterTuner) (or something similar) where *several* components of the pipeline have associated hyperparameters. Both components in our case are realized via SageMaker containers for ML algorithms.

```
model = PipelineModel(..., models = [ our_model, xgb_model ])
deploy = Estimator(image_uri = model, ...)
...
tuner = HyperparameterTuner(deply, .... tune_parameters, ....)
tuner.fit(...)
```

Now, there is of course the problem how to distribute the `tune_parameters` to the pipeline steps during the tuning.

In scikit-learn this is achieved by specially naming the tuning parameters `<StepName>__<ParameterName>`.

I don't see a way to achieve something similar with SageMaker, though. Also, search of the two keywords brings up the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56308169/creating-a-model-for-use-in-a-pipeline-from-a-hyperparameter-tuning-job) but is not really what we want to do.

Any suggestion how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both the models need to be jointly optimized, you could run a SageMaker HPO job in script mode and define both the models in the script. Or you could run two HPO jobs, optimize each model, and then create the Pipeline Model. There is no native support for doing an HPO job on a PipelineModel.

I work at AWS and my opinions are my own.

Comment: Thanks a lot. First of all it is good to hear a clear statement that HPO jobs over PipelineModels are not natively supported. This wasn't clear to me and we tried quite some time - obviously with failures ;-) Concerning the two options: the later one is not really possible, since the scoring comes from the second model, the first model is a kind of feature extraction that can be trained. Concerning the first option (HPO job in script mode and define both the models in the script) - are there any examples available in the sagemaker docs? Again, thanks a lot for your comment!