# Tuning Sagemaker Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Is it possible to do a hyper-parameter optimization on Sagemaker for a flow (e.g., pipeline) of a processing job followed by a training job?

In Sagemaker pipelines, I see I can use the tuner step with any training step. However, I can't see any helpful resource for integrating the processing job into the optimization.

Any ideas on how to do this task without merging two steps into one step?

In this relatively [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71346372/sagemaker-pipelinemodel-and-hyperparameter-tuning), it was asking about optimizing 2 models jointly. Here, I am asking about Processing and Training jobs.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run a [HyperparameterTuner](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/tuner.html) for Processor, it expects an estimator as an input. On the other hand, you can just put your processing logic with hyperparameters into an appropriate Estimator (`sklearn` for example) and then output processing script with hyperparameters as an artefact from `/opt/ml/model/model.joblib` into a S3 or as a model artefact. When done tuning, just load it into Processor via `model_dir`, and you got your Processor with tuned hyperparameters.